# How to disable back/left swipe gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

You can swipe from the left edge of the screen to go back on the navigation stack. But in my app, this behavior conflicts with my custom left menu. So, is it possible to disable this new gesture in UINavigationController?

Comment: If you have a left side menu bar for a view controller which is in a navigation controller at least one level deep, then that sounds like _bad UX_ to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the controller you want this to be enabled/disabled just

Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false // or true
```

ObjC:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; // or YES
```

Comment: where i can add this line ?

Comment: in the func viewDidLoad of the viewController that iw being displayed

Answer (score 2):

For my usecase it was important to disable it just in a single view controller, because that one had to have a slider which could easily interfere with that gesture. So I tried as suggested to disable it in viewWillAppear, which worked, however it kept being disabled in subsequently pushed controllers to.

I'v tried then to enable it in viewWillDisappear, which however did break the app somehow. Meaning, if in child view controllers I did try to use the back swipe the app was freezing. Putting it in background and reopen from there got rid of the freezing, but with nasty side-effects, like black backgrounds and missing search bars and other ui elements in wrong places.

The "trick" that got it working for me at the end was

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
}
```

and without setting it back to the real delegate it did work so far

Comment: on which viewConroller should I called ?? to the pushed ones or the main one(on which I want to disable swipeBack feature) ???

Comment: I do this in every controller where I'd like to disable it

Answer (score 0):

This feature set is not new as you are suggesting. If not wrong it was implemented in iOS 7 and can be found in all the subsequent releases. Its called interactivePopGestureRecognizer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621847-interactivepopgesturerecognizer

Fortunately for us, Apple has provided of a way to disable it. Set it to false at a suitable place.

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: i.m work on ios 12 where i can add this line ? before push viewcontroler

Comment: try inside ViewDidLoad method

Comment: if not then inside viewWillAppear. Let me know if you face any further issues

Comment: @DigvijayGida where exactly are you placing it?

Comment: viewWillAppear in. i'm not using segue push controller.

Comment: I dunno why but it works for me on iOS 11.3 simulator.

Comment: Yes it's work in new project. but still not working in my current  project. I'm use multiple story board and programmatically push viewcontroller.

Comment: code to push a viewcontroller or code to stop interactivePopGestureRecognizer??

Comment: Thanks for help me. @ioser

Comment: No is not work in my project, but is work in demo project.

Comment: Ah I see! I wonder why? If you think this answer works then please mark it as correct. So that it benefits others who come looking for the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Hi iOSer bro i'm pagecontroller in add view add push controller then this issue .

Comment: Bro I am confused!! Let me ask you again. Left swipe to previous view controller works on UIPageViewController? but not on another VC when pushed from UIPageViewController. Is it ? can you lay down the steps as opposed to when it working and when it not?

Comment: Well the way UIPageViewController works is based on gestures. Its probably capturing the swipe gesture, that you intend for going back to previous VC. I don't get it You started the question saying you want to disable the gesture in UINavigationController? but now somehow you want it in your UIPageViewController??

Comment: You dont have to vote to mark it as correct. You have to click on the tick make it  green indicating correct answer.